# Json Schema: How to inherit json schema from another schema

Tags: json, inheritance, overriding, schema

Is there any way where I can inherit another JSON schema from the parent and override firstname and lastname in feedbackperson schema

My scenario
I have a person schema and i want to duplicate it with FeedbackPerson schema but by using inheritence.

ex:

//Person Schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema",
  "description": "Personal and contact details of a customer",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "salutationAndTitle",
    "firstName",
    "lastName"

  ],
  "properties": {
    "salutationAndTitle": {
      "$ref": "../abcfd.json"
    },
    "firstName": {
      "$ref": "../FirstName.json"
    },
    "middleName": {
      "description": "Middle name",
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 31,
      "autocomplete": "additional-name",
      "x-faker": "name.firstName",
      "example": "abc"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "$ref": "../LastName.json"
    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried combining $ref and allOf as suggested at [JSON Schema docs](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#extending)? PersonSchema could be the general schema without firstname and lastname properties. Then FeedbackPerson could refer PersonSchema and require all of firstname and lastname properties.